# Pre-defined color picking in the node admin in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I want the user to select one of the predefined color for one my Article fields.

I am unable to find a suitable way for the user to do so though. What I want is that there is a color picker of selected colors and user is able to pick on.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. What is these predefined colors, is they defined by you and how are you planning on using the actual value in an article e.g if an article has the color red is this just an attribute for the actual node? Does it matter how a color is stored in the database i.e as an integer, string, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment I'm having trouble understanding the actual question. If you want a user to be able to choose from a set of predefined colors and connect this value to a node of type `article` you could do like this:

- Visit `admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields`
- Add a new field of type `List (text)`
- Set the widget to `Selectlist` and press save
- On the next page under `Allowed values list` you then enter all your colors in the form `key|value` for instance `Red|Red` or `Black|Black` and then press `Save field settings`
- In the next form you might set if this field is required or not and a default value

Now your users can select a color from a select list on the article edit screen. Not sure this is what you're asking for though.

Here is an example of what the user will see when editing an article:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Color Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/color_field) is the module which exactly meets your requirement.